# Stripe.StripeException: 'The Issuing API is currently in private beta. Please visit https://stripe.com/issuing for more information.'

Tags: asp.net-core, stripe-payments

Error is coming while returning list of payment history in stripe, below is the code and image is attached:

```
public TransactionService StripeGetListTransaction()
        {
            ResponseModel response = new ResponseModel();
            StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = _paymentSettings.Value.SecretKey;


            var options = new TransactionListOptions
            {
                Limit = 3,
            };
            var service = new TransactionService();
            service.List(options);
            return service;

        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6guoP.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong service class. 
For listing balance transactions, you should use `BalanceTransactionService` instead

```
var options = new BalanceTransactionListOptions
{
  Limit = 3,
};
var service = new BalanceTransactionService();
service.List(options);
```

See the [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/list?lang=dotnet) for more information